# Qr-Code using Bacon/BaconQrCode need to save to the folder.

Tags: php, qr-code, magento-2.0

I am using Bacon/BaconQrCode library to generate Qr-Code image so how can 
save the Qr-code images to the specific folder ?? please help.

My Code:-

```
    $renderer = new \BaconQrCode\Renderer\Image\Png();
    $renderer->setHeight(256);
    $renderer->setWidth(256);
    $writer = new \BaconQrCode\Writer($renderer);
    $writer->writeFile('www.google.com', 'qrcode.png');
```

How can I save this Qr-code image to the folder to show or fetch from other location.

Answer (score 0):

The \BaconQrCode\Writer->writeFile uses file_put_contents method so you can just add an absolute path to your directory like : $writer->writeFile('www.google.com', '../public/qrcodes/qrcode.png');

I haven't tried yet but i hope it works for you.